# Is pulling from both SVN and Git possible in a single Azure Pipeline?

Tags: azure-pipelines

I'm trying to set up an Azure DevOps pipeline to build a C++ project.  The project source code lives right in Azure DevOps Git but it relies on third party libraries (binaries and headers) that are stored in a separate SVN Server.

Is there a way to do this?  The [documentation for YAML pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#type) makes it sound like I can only use multiple sources if they are git, github or bitbucket.  So even though I have an Azure server connection to the SVN server it seems like I can only use it if that's the *only* place the pipeline wants to pull from.

The manual process that I need to replicate in the pipeline is as follows:

1. Grab my project source code from Azure DevOps Git
2. Grab the ThirdParty stuff from the SVN Server
3. Move/copy the ThirdParty binaries into my build output folder
4. Build my project

Can this be done?  If so, how?

Comment: After two more days of searching around how to do this. I'm hoping that creating some Azure Universal Packages from the bits of the external SVN repository I need might be the solution.  Anyone else tried this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer my own question because I did "sort-of" find and answer.  I won't mark this as *the* answer because maybe someone has a better idea.

My solution was to pull the svn code I needed, then publish it to the Azure DevOps project as a Universal Artifact.  It involved quite a bit of command line stuff and installing the Azure CLI plus the "devops" extension.  But it let me put all the 3rd party binaries I need there and then I could just pull it in my pipeline with a task.  This is the task I use

```
- task: UniversalPackages@0
  displayName: 'ThirdParty download'
  inputs:
    command: download
    vstsFeed: Software/SoftwareInternalFeed               
    vstsFeedPackage: 'thirdparty-windows'               # Name of package
    vstsPackageVersion: 1.0.0                             # Semantic version of package
    downloadDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\ThirdParty'
```

There are many steps with this, including making myself a personal access token and but it does work